# Powershell- How to wrap a specific line in an array object in double quotes?

Tags: powershell

Lets say I have a text file whose content is this:

```
======= Section 1 ==========
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
======= Section 2 ==========
This is line Four
This is line Five
This is line Six
```

I import it into Powershell using `$SourceFile = Get-Content '.\source.txt' -Delimiter '==='`
then clean it up with `$Objects = $SourceFile -replace '^=.*', ''`
I now have this `$Objects` array that has:

```
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
```

and

```
This is line Four
This is line Five
This is line Six
```

What I really want to know is how can I wrap a specific line in double quotes or parenthesis etc, so that specific line in all the objects arrays are also handled the same way.

For example line 3 of both arrays should have double quotes wrapped around them:

```
This is line one
This is line two
"This is line three"
```

and

```
This is line Four
This is line Five
"This is line Six"
```

I have tried many things, closest I got was `$test =  $objects -replace 'This is line three', '"This is line three"'` As you can see this is less than ideal for an object of many arrays.

I am still fairly new to Powershell, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How would you want that defined? The third line or each multi-line string? The last line? Specific keywords? That makes a big difference. Easiest way I can think of would be `$Objects|%{$_ -replace '(?<=[\r\n])(.+)$','"$1"'}` which would add quotes to the last line of each multi-line string.

Comment: Guess an alternate solution to Mad's suggestion would be using the index, or the last object in the case with `Select-Object -Last 1`. So, something like `$first,$sec | % { $last = $_ | Select -Last 1;$_ -replace $last,"""$last"""}`?

Comment: You're writing "a specific line" … How do you specify "a specific line"? – The code you've written in your question makes perfect sense if "a specific line" means the literal text in a line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to wrap the 3rd line in each block in double quotes:

```bash
# Read the input file and split it into blocks of lines by a
# regex matching the section lines (without including the section lines).
(Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -split '(?m)^===.*\r?\n' -ne '' |
  ForEach-Object {  # Process each block of lines (multi-line string)
    # Split this block into individual lines, ignoring a trailing newline.
    $linesInBlock = $_ -replace '\r?\n\z' -split '\r?\n' 
    # Modify the 3rd line.
    $linesInBlock[2] = '"{0}"' -f $linesInBlock[2]
    # Output the lines, including the modification.
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "-- next block"
    $linesInBlock
  }
```

Output with your sample input:

```bash
VERBOSE: -- next block
This is line one
This is line two
"This is line three"
VERBOSE: -- next block
This is line Four
This is line Five
"This is line Six"
```